# findViewById problems for webview in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, webview

I'm getting something wrong with setcontentview & findviewbyid. I'm trying to pull up a webpage when the user, using the navigation drawer, clicks on the blackboard button.

fragment.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class BlackBoardFragment extends Fragment {

public BlackBoardFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blackboard, container, false);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public View onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState){

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    return myWebView;
}
}
```

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

I have been stuck on this for the past couple of days.
Thanks in advance!!!

-David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `fragment_blackboard.xml` must contain your `Webview`, remember you are inside a `Fragment` :

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This method must return Void! not View:

```
@Override
public View onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

Your code must looks like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blackboard, container, false);
  WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <WebView  
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```